# How to move the values from one field in jsonb column to another in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a jsonb column with a field "tags":{"choices":{choice}} and I want to move "choices" to another field "questions":{} in the same jsonb column.

Could you please let me know how to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PostgreSQL (9.5/9.6 +) JSONB functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) jsonb_set or jsonb_insert, or combine both, for example with jsonb_set

```
postgres=# SELECT myjsonb old_value,   jsonb_set(myjsonb,'{tags}', 
text('{"choices":"{}","questions":'||text(myjsonb->'tags'- 
>'choices')||'}')::jsonb) as new_value
postgres-# 
postgres-#  FROM (VALUES ('{"tags":{"choices":"{choice1}","questions":"{}" 
}}'::jsonb), ('{"tags":{"choices":"{choice2}","questions":"{}" }}'::jsonb)) AS 
t (myjsonb);

                       old_value                       |                       new_value                       
-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
{"tags": {"choices": "{choice1}", "questions": "{}"}} | {"tags": {"choices": "{}", "questions": "{choice1}"}}
{"tags": {"choices": "{choice2}", "questions": "{}"}} | {"tags": {"choices": "{}", "questions": "{choice2}"}}
(2 filas)
```

Comment: my jsonb column is as follows


document{
tags:{choices:["choice"]},
questions:{ }
}

can I move choices from **tags to questions**

Comment: @sanj the { tags:{choices:["choice"]}, questions:{ } } not is a json valid, please adjust what i  said above about the use of the function jsonb_set in your case:




`code`
SELECT myjsonb old_value,   jsonb_set(myjsonb,'{tags}', text('{"choices":"{}","questions":'||text(myjsonb->'tags'->'choices')||'}')::jsonb) as new_value
FROM (VALUES ('{"tags":{"choices":["choice1"],"questions":"{}" }}'::jsonb), ('{"tags":{"choices":["choice"],"questions":"{}" }}'::jsonb)) AS 
t (myjsonb);